# How can I call selfdestruct when it is located in a constructor and not in the ABI of my contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, selfdestruct

I am reading some tutorials and while planning to deploy test contract on ropsten I have something like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract destroy {
    constructor(address payable receiver) public payable {
        selfdestruct(receiver);
    }
}

contract Test {

     function() external payable { }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) external {
       ///
    }

}
```

Getting "transfer" from the abi is quite easy. But what to do with "contract destroy"? Not only is this another contract but also everything is in the constructor? Is there a way to call this from web3 python/js or at least via myetherwallet? 10x!

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do here. It's not clear what the relationship between those two contracts is, what functions you want to invoke, and in general - what exactly you are having difficulties with.

Comment: I want to invoke selfdestruct, but is this evne possible given the way this is written? Obviously contract destroy is included in "Test" but is there a way to invoke selfdestruct since it's not in a function? Basically i want to invoke selfdesctruct without using onlyowner as modifier since I want to be able to use several addresses and not only the "owner" but looking for various ways to achieve his...hence this got me curious.

Comment: `contract destroy is included in "Test"` - what does that mean???

Comment: `is there a way to invoke selfdestruct since it's not in a function` - it's in the constructor of contract `destroy`, so simply deploy this contract in order to invoke the function.

Comment: `without using onlyowner as modifier since I want to be able to use several addresses and not only the "owner"` - where is there anything related to "owner" anywhere in your code??? Please provide ALL the relevant information (and ONLY the relevant information).

Comment: i am now testing on remix...basically Test gets deployed on some address and it seems as if the idea here is that "destroy" doesn't get deployed but its goal is to be deployed to a new address ans get the funds from Test...which still leaves the original question: how can "destroy" get called, maybe just use it as a regular function via say python?

Comment: Replaying my comment above - this function is in the constructor of contract destroy, so simply deploy this contract in order to invoke the function.

Comment: ok but I am missing the logic here, if I deploy "destroy" to a new address it will simply hold 0 ether and with "receiver" as argument it will send 0 to the receiver without getting anything from test. The basic idea as far as I wanted is to use "destroy" to pull all the ether from Test and safely destroy both....it looks like I am missing something from the tutorial and the idea...thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: You can't get one contract to withdraw funds from another contract without any mechanism in the other contract to support this operation (imagine what this network would be worth if you could do something like that).